# Updating plugin to Craft 3: craft()->urlManager->setRouteVariables?

Tags: plugin-development, craft3

What would be the Craft 3 / Yii 2.0 version of
`craft()->urlManager->setRouteVariables(array('calupdateResponse' => $out));`

This doesn't work (it doesn't complain, either):

```
$urlManager = new UrlManager;
$urlManager->setRouteParams(['calupdateResponse' => $out]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Craft::$app->getUrlManager()->setRouteParams(['calupdateResponse' => $out]);
```

All `Components` should be treated as singletons, don't create a new instance of them

Note: you can also do

```
Craft::$app->urlManager->setRouteParams(['calupdateResponse' => $out]);
```

But it is considered as [bad practice](https://github.com/craftcms/docs/blob/v3/en/coding-guidelines.md#app-component-getters)

Edit: most parts of Craft 3 are working with Craft 2 as well... `craft()` is just a mapper for `Craft::$app`

Comment: Thank you, Robin. Works perfectly. And thank you for the programming tips. Does `Components` refer to things accessed by `use Craft;` or `use craft\web\Request`? For instance  
```$request = new Request;  
$timestr  = $request->getParam('time1');```

Comment: Components are all classes, that `extends Component`. All these have global access from everywhere (Twig & PHP) via `Craft::$app->` and they are usually placed in a `services` folder. Examples are `Craft::$app->entries`, `Craft::$app->sections`, `Craft::$app->fields` and so on. You can see the entire list here https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-services-api.html grouped in `craft\services`. Btw.... **don't** do `$request = new Request; ` instead `Craft::$app->getRequest()`

Comment: This is very helpful. Does this guidance apply to plugin classes that `extends Component`?  So in my variable.php, I should replace `$service = new Service;` with `return Service::calendar()` and in the Service, the functions should all be `public static function` ?

Comment: Please read the docs https://github.com/craftcms/docs/blob/v3/en/services.md#what-are-services of course it is the same for Plugin components... just do `MyPlugin::getInstance()->serviceName`.